# LoadState() Method.

Tags: apex, callout, method

I have a question in regards to a LoadState() method I found. I have been trying to find some information after seeing this method on an Apex @future(Callout=true)class.
I know this method exist in Java: [LoadState Java EE6](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/LoadState.html)

So, is this method available in Apex? I have been searching for a while and can't find anything on the dev. documentation. 
On the class I mentioned it is declared like this:

*CustomObejct__c State = LoadState();*

Would be nice if anyone has any Apex information, if available, in connection to this method.

Thanks.

Comment: did you search in all your classes to make sure its not a local method ?

Comment: good point ... let me just do that ...